# How to emulate PuTTY raw connection in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ethernet

Please forgive my ignorance, but I believe I just need to be pointed in the right direction...

I have a device that communicates with my PC via Ethernet. I open PuTTY, put in the IP, port, and select a raw connection type. After successful connection, I can then type an "R" to receive one sample from this device. This works without issue.

I've tried many examples I've found for achieving this exact thing in C# (MSDN socket examples, blog examples) and everything so far has fallen short.

```
 private static void StartClient()
{
    // Connect to a remote device.  
    try
    { 
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.4");
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Raw);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();

        var isConnected = client.Connected;

        // Send test data to the remote device.  
        Send(client, "S");
        sendDone.WaitOne();
```

I modified this example (from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) to include the IP and port I'm using and I attempted to change the SocketType and ProtocolType to raw. The device's datasheet does say that it ships with TCP as it's default.

I cannot establish a connection to this device at all, let alone write to and read from it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not enough context in your question to provide an actual answer. You should check to make sure you're using the right `port` value. You also most likely should _not_ be using the `Raw` protocol type. If it's TCP, use `SocketType.Stream` and `ProtocolType.Tcp`. It should not affect your result, but I would also advise using the synchronous `Connect()` method if all you're going to do is wait synchronously for the operation to complete. Don't waste time with the `BeginConnect()`, callback, etc. if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for the response Peter. I actually just got it working... I sniffed out the packet coming from PuTTY just to make sure it was configured correctly (there was a \r\n I was forgetting!). I changed back from raw to .Stream and .Tcp. All is well. Thanks again!