# Replicate PuTTY's raw connection with sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, putty, ethernet

I am working with a heat cell with which i can only communicate through Ethernet. When trying to connect to it using sockets, I am stuck on waiting for the Receive() method to end.

I've checked the connection using PuTTY in raw mode and it worked just fine, I was able to send and receive messages. [image]

This led me to believe that I needed to use some kind of raw communication as well, hence why I tried to use SharpPCap and the like. Using this, I am able to read from the cell (although I am faced with a few issues that aren't related to this post).

However, since I'm not very experienced with networking, I was wondering if there was a way to obtain the same results as when I used PuTTY's raw mode but using only Sockets ?

I've come accross  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279307/how-to-emulate-putty-raw-connection-in-c) that was left unanswered, apart from the fact that the author was advised not to use SocketType.Raw.

Below is the [example from MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket?view=net-6.0) that I adapted for my tests. It is supposed to send a request and then listen for the answer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.IPAddress host = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.3");
        int port = 2049;

        Socket socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        socket.Connect(host, port);

        if (socket.Connected)
        {
            string request = "99997¶1¶1\\r";

            var byteSent = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(request);
            var byteReceived = new byte[256]; 

            socket.Send(byteSent, byteSent.Length, 0);

            int bytes = 0;
            do
            {
                bytes = socket.Receive(byteReceived, byteReceived.Length, 0); // this is the line I'm being stuck on
            } while (bytes > 0);

            Console.WriteLine($"Result : {Encoding.Default.GetString(byteReceived)}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Failed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I used WireShark to take a look at what was being sent from my application. Turns out the 'CR' and 'LF' werent sent correctly. But correcting this didn't solve my problem.

I can see the server's answer to my request on WireShark, but still I can't read anything using socket.Receive(). Could it be possible that the server is faster to answer than my machine is to start listening ? I tried setting up the socket.ReceiveTimeout property and put my send/receive instructions in a loop, but still nothing returning from the Receive() statement.

Comment: Are you sure the server isn't waiting for you to send some more bytes? Also does the C# socket.Send function send all the bytes?

Comment: The Net managed library does not support all IP protocols.  Raw mode has an IP header with a fixed number of bytes (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) which is not supported with Net.  The work around is to use pinvoke to send/receive the IP.  See : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ws2_32/send.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: PuTTY raw mode has nothing to do with "raw" sockets. It's just straight TCP without any additional protocol interpretation above TCP.

Answer (score 0):

The socket is in blocking mode by default (cf [Socket.Blocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.blocking?view=net-6.0#system-net-sockets-socket-blocking)). That mean that, for your case, blocking until 256 byte has been read (Without timeout by default [Socket.ReceiveTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout?view=net-6.0)).

You may want to set the Blocking mode to false, or set a Receive timeout in order to not block indefinitly.

Alternatively, you may want also to use async method to avoid blocking the main thread.

Comment: Blocking mode means it will block until it receives *some* data, not necessarily until it receives 256 bytes. That's why the methods returns the number of bytes it received.